# Desktop redirected Icons

Tags: group-policy, desktop

I need to set a static custom icon for a website's shortcut. The desktop is redirected on a server 2008 domain via GP.  Need an easily recognizable icon for young children versus having Chrome or IE generic icons. How do I take an existing icon file and apply it to my specific website shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the shortcut properties, click change icon, set icon, copy the shortcut to your redirected desktop location.